# Why AFNetworking always go into Failure block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I have integrated AFNetworking from [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) in my project. But when I do get request using AFNetworking, it always go into the Failure block. Below is my code. Please let me know, What I am doing wrong here?

```
NSString *baseUrl = @"http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/acromine/dictionary.py?sf=ETA";
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:baseUrl parameters:nil progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

   //Always it invoke the Failure block
    }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey];
        NSInteger statusCode = response.statusCode;
        NSLog(@"Error Code=%ld",statusCode);
        NSLog(@"Desc=%@",response.description);
    }];
```

Note:- This is the valid URL.
http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/acromine/dictionary.py?sf=ETA

Also below is the error code and description:-

```
Error Code 200
Error Description <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fbab8509860> { URL: http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/acromine/dictionary.py?sb=hmm } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Wed, 20 Apr 2016 00:17:27 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.15 (Scientific Linux)";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} }
```

Comment: Have you add app transport security to allow http connection in your plist?

Comment: What is the error you are getting in the failure block?

Comment: It returns the status code 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer :-

```
NSString *url = @"http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/acromine/dictionary.py?sf=hmm";
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

//Missing this line (Any request or response serializer dealing with HTTP is encouraged to subclass)
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:url parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                                                             options:kNilOptions
                                                               error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Success= %@",json);

    }failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey];
        NSInteger statusCode = response.statusCode;
        NSLog(@"Fail=%ld",statusCode);
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the error description, and you'll see the helpful explanation

> Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain"

The correct fix is to make the content-type `application/json`, as it does appear to be JSON.

Comment: But I do not have this error description. My error is different

Comment: Sure you're checking "error.description"? Your source above is checking "response.description". If it actually is different, post it here!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the type of response that AFNetworking is looking for. If you explicitly tell it to expect a text/plain response then you should have your success callback executed. The following line of code directly following where you init your ***manager*** object should do:

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];
```